# How to get the link count of a directory that has multiple directories inside of it?

Tags: linux, ls

I was thinking that it would be the sum of the link counts within the directories?

Comment: No, it's just the count of subdirectories + 2.

Comment: Each directory has a `..` link to its parent. There are no links to the grandparent, so directories further down don't increase the link count of the top directory.

Comment: If you want to get the total, you need to write a function that loops and recurses.

Comment: No, that will just show the link count of the directory. That only counts the direct subdirectories, not all the descendants.

Comment: did that help you? *find ./ -type d | wc -l*

Answer (score 5):

The link count is not about directories, it is about inodes. The link count is essentially a reference count.

- an inode is the basic object inside a filesytem
- directory entries link to *inode*s
- a directory *has* an inode, too, just like a plain file
- every link counts: a directory entry that links to an inode adds 1 to the count, so inodes that are referenced by *two* directory-entries have a link count of two.
- a link to the parent directory is also a link for *this* directory (this is a safeguard to protect against *orphan* directories)
- when the link count for an inode goes to zero it is unreferenced, and the inode (and associated diskblocks, or whatever) can be discarded as well
- ["open" files invisibly have a similar mechanism]
- symlinks don't count: when a symlink to a file is added/removed, its link count will not be affected. (thus: you can symlink to a non-existent file)

Answer (score 0):

you can use tree utility to see the count of directories.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linux **find** utility has an option *-type d* to filter certain type (directory, file, symbolic link, socket or other) so it should help alongside with *wc -l* to count number of STDOUT lines:

```
find ./ -type d | wc -l
```

If you need to limit number of nested directories use *-maxdepth* parameter:

```
find ./ -type d -maxdepth 2 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to sum up the link count of all the subdirectories?

What's exactly the purpose, may I ask?

You could do something similar to [Unix find average file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195493/unix-find-average-file-size/14393581#14393581):

```
find ./ -type d -ls | awk '{sum += $4;} END {print sum;}'
```

You could even find the average link count, whilst at it:

```
find ./ -type d -ls | awk '{sum += $4; n++;} END {print sum/n;}'
```