# Unix find average number of files in directory

Tags: bash, unix

I have files in directory and I want to know average number of this files in BASH.I am in folder where are 4 files and I want to write a code which will give me average number of files in this directory. I find something common [Unix find average file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195493/unix-find-average-file-size) but this give me average file size but I want to gain average number or amount of this files.

Comment: You have a directory (A) containing directories (B) that all contains files and you need to know the average number of files in those directories (B)?

Comment: Please be more specific what the approach is

Comment: I am writing script which will write all directories, maximum depth of biggest directory and the last thing I need is the average number/amount of files in this directory. But i don´t know how to get it.

Comment: @DavidMorientes `N/1` is `N`. I don't understand what you mean when you say average files in this directory? You have directories with the same name located multiply places?

Comment: I mean script which will wrote me the average number of files in directory for example - path/to/izp/proj3 ..so in this directory are 3 files so average will be 3 but if i will have more directories with more or less files than it will make me average of files in these directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FILES=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
DIRS=$(find . -type d | wc -l)
AVG=$(($FILES / $DIRS))
echo $AVG
```

Note this has integer precision, i.e. whole numbers without decimals.
To get 3 decimal positions, use this hack (OK don't sue me):

```
AVG=$((1000 * $FILES / $DIRS))
echo $AVG | sed "s/\(...\)$/\.\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tree -F` command. It will do the most of job you need. For example,

Go to /dir1/dir2/lib/python3.4/venv python library dir and type tree -F. Then, you will get the following lines. The one ending with / is a directory. And you can figure out subdirectory structure by counting the number of | in the line.

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- __pycache__/
|   |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
|   `-- __init__.cpython-34.pyo
`-- futures/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __pycache__/
    |   |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    |   |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyo
    |   |-- _base.cpython-34.pyc
    |   |-- _base.cpython-34.pyo
    |   |-- process.cpython-34.pyc
    |   |-- process.cpython-34.pyo
    |   |-- thread.cpython-34.pyc
    |   `-- thread.cpython-34.pyo
    |-- _base.py
    |-- process.py
    `-- thread.py
```

In other words, most of work is done by tree -F command.